# How to set notification status icon with Firebase FCM (using Admin SDK's sendToDevice or HTTP)?

Tags: node.js, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

After managing to send notifications and setting the icon in the notification message, I would like to set the status bar notification icon. In the Android SDK there is a `setSmallIcon` method on the `NotificationBuilder`. What is the equivalent property of the notification object in the Firebase node.js Admin SDK?

In case you forget what the status bar icon is, here is a picture of some:
[image]

If there is no equivalent, how can one be hacked?

Comment: Have you tried setting the [`icon`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) param in your payload yet?

Comment: @AL. yes. This `icon` parameter sets the icon appearing in the notification. I'm looking for the status bar icon.

Comment: Owww. Okay. I was looking at the Android Icon in your image. You meant the smaller ones. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks. Cropped the image properly.